# Is it possible to access template reference variable from a different component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

This is Component A

```
@Component({
selector:'component-a',
template: `<div>
              <div>Component A</div>
              <div>some other data</div>
              <ng-template #a_one>A one</ng-template>
           </div>`
})
export class Component A {
 constructor() {}
}
```

Component B:

```
@Component({
selector:'component-b',
template: `<div>
              <div>Component B</div>
              <div>some other data</div>
              <div *ngIf='flag; then a_one; else b_one'></div>
              <ng-template #b_one>B one</ng-template>
           </div>`
})
export class Component B {
 @Input() flag: boolean;
 constructor() {}
}
```

I want to access a_one from Component A rather than duplicating the code. Is it possible in Angular 4?

Comment: I don't understand what is not clear? I want to reuse a template in another component rather than creating it again.

Comment: you will not have to create it again, web components are meant for this usage, you can simply add your component everywhere you need it. Your example is confusing, mainly because of your *ngIf clause. 
If I understand well, you want to show one template or another base on a boolean expression?

Comment: You need to pass it around so that other components can reuse it.